# Run method from war application automatically after tomcat server startup

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Project is a war using local tomcat

I'm wondering how to run a method automatically after server startup?  I know of ways to run it DURING server startup such as @Bean method or during context initialization, but how can I do it AFTER the server successfully starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Spring Boot, adding the @PostConstruct annotation to the method causes it to run after the Spring Boot application starts up.

Comment: Thanks, one of the simpliest method i found

Answer (score 2):

On Tomcat, you can use the Tomcat-own [LifecycleListener](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/LifecycleListener.html). If you register a listener for the AFTER_START_EVENT on the host component, you should get what you want.

Code-Example of a LifecycleListener:

```
package my.sourcecode;

import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;

public class TomcatHostLifecycleListener implements LifecycleListener {

@Override
public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifeCE) {

    if (Lifecycle.AFTER_START_EVENT.equals(lifeCE.getType())) {
        System.out.println("************ TomcatHostLifecycleListener: After Start Event");
    }

}

}
```

The code must be be placed as JAR-File inside the global lib-folder of Tomcat!

A LifecycleListener has to be registerd in Tomcats *server.xml*, in your case inside the host element, because we want to listen to host startup:

```
....
<Host ... >
    <Listener className="my.sourcecode.TomcatHostLifecycleListener"/>
    ....
```

See [Lifecycle-Doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html) for further documentation.

(Tested with Tomcat 8.5.30 and Java 11)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you are using Spring. So you can look on Spring application context events.
For example you can define event listener method like that

```
@EventListener
public void handleContextRefreshEvent(ContextStartedEvent ctxStartEvt) {
    System.out.println("Context Start Event received.");
}
```

Comment: Spring has no way of knowing when the Tomcat listen port is opened, ContextStartedEvent might happen before the port is open.